# Bind the listener to dynamic generate content in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There is a dynamic generate page using jquery like this:

var html = "tab...button..datatable...etc...";

And I generate the page when click on a button

```
$("btn").on("click",function(){
     $("body").append(html);
});
```

The problem is , all element from generated html does not have event listener, so for the click button /change event I use

```
 $('body').on('change', '.gui-file', function (event) {
```

However, for the bootstrap element how can I bind the event to the generated element ? e.g. Tab?

Or are there any better way other than binding after generate the html content? Thanks

The tab:

```
                             <div class="tab-block mb10">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-left tabs-border">
                                        <li class="active">
                                            <a href="#tab1_1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">English</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="">
                                            <a href="#tab1_2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">繁體</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="">
                                            <a href="#tab1_3" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">简体</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                        <div id="tab1_1" class="tab-pane active">
</div>
<div id="tab1_2" class="tab-pane">
</div>
<div id="tab1_3" class="tab-pane">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Read about [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: do you have any fiddle for this?

Comment: Why not use the `data-toggle="tab"` markup as specified by the [Bootstrap documentation here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#markup)...?

Comment: already have that, please check update question

Comment: Could you try triggering document ready and window load after body append html.

Comment: Is it call $.ready(); ? seems nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please init newly added tab by calling:

```
$("btn").on("click",function(){
     $("body").append(html);
     $(".nav-tabs").tab();
});
```